# How proof of stake prevent blockchain rebuild

Tags: blockchain, consensus

In proof of work, if we tamper a block, re-mining the entire blockchain from that block requires huge computation power. But in proof of stake, nouce is not that hard to found. So is it possible to tamper a block and rebuild subsequent blockchain? Or proof of stake has some other way to prevent this?

Comment: I have been wondering about the same. Although I am far from sure, I think the answer might be that yes, you could relatively easy create a chain of new blocks but the p2p system of nodes would not accept it since you are not the chosen validator - thus you will not be able to create that one newest block that has a sort of pointer to your newly constructed "fake" blockchain.

Answer (score 1):

POS has the same idea as POW. The difference is, instead of computational (CPU/GPU) power, in POS the miners that own the most number of coin would have the power to make changes in the chain. To attack a blockchain network based on POS, the attacker will need to acquire more than 50% of all the coins in circulation.

Answer (score 1):

Careful observation will undoubtedly lead us to the fact that Proof of Stake is indeed the mechanism that saves the very ideology of Blockchain.

**No Centralization (Eliminating the 51% Attack Threat)**

As already discussed, Proof of Work, irresponsibly, lets everyone validate the blocks which has ultimately lead to a point where miners gradually started combining their resources and forming Mining Pools, thus enhancing their chances of mining more blocks and earn more rewards.

Since these pools soon started controlling a large part of the network, thus centralizing the mining process which challenges the Blockchain’s idea of Decentralization.

Proof of Stake, on the other hand, doesn’t let everyone mine the blocks and choose only those with enough experience as well as deposits. Therefore, there is absolutely no chance for validators to join hands and form a pool, yet No CENTRALIZATION. And since there is no centralization, the 51% attack threat is also minimized to a greater extent.

**Reduced Power Consumption**

The power consumption by this consensus mechanism turned out to be really low. Therefore, Proof of Stake is the one effective answer to the massive energy consumption by Proof of Work.

While Proof of Work uses 77 TWh of Electricity, Proof of Stake uses just 7.7 TWh as of now.

**No Fraudulent Transactions**

Since PoS chooses the validators randomly, a really concerning dilemma might pop up in your brain.

```
How can we Trust these Validators?

Well, Blockchain quite clearly believes in the fact that Internet is a Trustless community. And Proof of Stake respects this ideology.
```

PoS takes very good care of your transactions and provides a really strict policy for validators who try fraudulent transactions.

Just in case a validators try to validate a fake transaction, the algorithm ensures that they lose an enormous part of their stakes. In simpler terms, we can trust validators because if they approve fraudulent transactions, they lose more money than they gain through the fraud. And, truth be told, no one would ever agree for such a bad deal.